# How to show Cantor function is uniformly continuous?

Tags: functions, continuity, uniform-continuity

> **Cantor function $f$ is defined by**
>
> $f: \Delta \to [0,1]$ by $$f(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2b_n}{3^n}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_n}{2^n}, b_n \in \{0,1\}$$, where $\Delta$ is a Cantor set and each $x\in\Delta$ can be written as $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2b_n}{3^n}$, where $b_n = 0$ or $1$.

I read "Cantor function is uniformly continuous" on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function and wiki also claims that it is Holder continuous of exponent $\alpha = \frac {\log2}{\log3}$. So how to prove it is uniformly continuous and even how to get $\alpha = \frac {\log2}{\log3}$?

Comment: it is enough to show that it is continuous since it is defined on a compact set.

Comment: Look at the first base 3 digit where the two numbers differ. Since $2^n < 3^n/2$, the difference of the f's is less than the difference of the va;ues, so you can always take $\delta = \epsilon$. Similarly, $\log(2^n)/\log(3^n) = \log 2/\log 3$.

Comment: @DanielAkech: Make sense.

Comment: @martycohen: Correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to show that it is Holder continuous.
Suppose $0 < \alpha < \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3} < 1$. 
Take any two points $x, y \in [0,1]$. There exists some $n$ such that $|x - y| > 3^{-n}$ (the Archimedian property).

Then $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \left|f(\frac{k}{3^{n}}) - f(\frac{k +1}{3^{n}})\right|\leq \left|\frac{m}{2^{n}} - \frac{m +1}{2^{n}}\right| \leq \frac{1}{2^{n}}\leq \left(\frac{1}{3^{n}} \right)^{\alpha} < M|x-y|^{\alpha}$, for an appropriate choice of M.